# track row inserts from remote database

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Have read-only remote database. Need to check for new inserted rows in it and then insert rows into local db. Now see only one solution with querying db and filtering by time:

```
local_engine, remote_engine = create_engine('db_url'), create_engine('db_url')
Local_Session, Remote_Session = sessionmaker(bind=local_engine), sessionmaker(bind=remote_engine)
local_session, remote_session = Local_Session(), Remote_Session()

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(local_engine)

class Model(Base):
    __table__ = Base_class.metadata.tables['table']

while True:
    lastest_date = local_session.query(Model).order_by(desc(Model.datefield)).first().datefield
    new_rows = remote_session.query(Model).filter(Model.datefield > lastest_date).all()
    #####
    time.sleep(60)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it (track new rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options you can use to solve this task. I'll name two.

The first one can be considered as of "pull" style, the second one -- as "push". (So if you have limited access to remote DBs, the second one is probably not a real option.)

1) Use postgres_fdw extension and work with remote tables locally. While you won't be able to track changes like you'd do it with regular tables with triggers, you can query such tables and in many cases work with them quite efficiently (some things -- e.g. `select count(*)` -- are slow in 9.6 and  are improved in 10, which will be released in a month or so). You can also create a materialized view on top of FDW table, with needed indexes to achieve better performance.

If you choose this option, you'd probably find very useful `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA` statement, it *significantly* simplifies the maintenance.

2) Use logical replication -- with it, you'll be able to receive true signals on each data change on remote side, you choose what to take and how to process. Check out "pglogical" extension by 2ndQuadrant.

This way is probably the most powerful and flexible, and it's how complex integrations are supposed to be made these days.

P. S. Sorry no links -- typing it on smartphone.